# How to automate this drop-cap-like effect

Tags: tikz-pgf, drop-cap

In a website I saw the below drop-cap-like effect and I wanted to replicate it.

[image]

For a one-time case one can do it manually. See the MWE.

How can I automate the process? So that I can start a parapgraph with, say, `\dropcapeffect[size = , color=, text opacity=, horizontal pos=]{L}` .. etc.?

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, color=lightgray]
    \node[text opacity=0.2] at  ($ (current page.north west) + (3pc, -7.5pc) $) {\fontsize{80pt}{80pt}\selectfont L};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\begin{document}
\rlap{\lettrine[
lines=8,
loversize=-0.05,
findent=-50pt,]{\color{gray!10}H}{}}
\noindent How much \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\dropcapeffect}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, anchor=north east, baseline=-1ex]
\node[lightgray, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] {\scalebox{2.4}{\Huge #1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent \dropcapeffect{L}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{document}
```

[image: Large gray "L" left of text]

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples using package `lettrine`. Unfortunately your initial post leaves some desired effects unmentioned, i.e. are underspecified. So here are some inline examples and some self-defined macros.

Looks like you need to use LuaLaTeX.

Macro `\two{}` abstracts the inlies for a character span of two lines. Macro `\four{}` does the same for 4 lines AND changes color, too, using package `xcolor`.

`\lettrine{}{}` takes two arguments, e.g. to handle **L** *ore ...* individually. With your approach, just replicating the character, you could move the typeset `\lettrine` also to the left, before the line, using "classical" LaTeX commands.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% ~~~ shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\two[1]{\lettrine[lines=2,realheight=true]{#1}{}}
\newcommand\four[1]{\lettrine[lines=4,realheight=true]{\textcolor[gray]{0.8}{#1}}{}}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\noindent \two{U} Use \emph{LuaLaTeX} to\\
compile.\bigskip\bigskip

\noindent \lettrine{L}{} \lipsum[1]
\bigskip\bigskip

\noindent \lettrine[lines=4,realheight=true]{L}{} \lipsum[1]
\bigskip\bigskip

\noindent \four{L} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```